# Is it possible to export from the Photos app without the dual dialogs?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

In the macOS Photos app, select one or more photos and then choose *> File > Export > Export 1 Photo*. A popup dialog appears with options for the exported image:

[image]

Accept the defaults then choose Export, at which time a second dialog appears asking where the images should be stored. This also applies if you use the keyboard shortcut *shift-command-E*.

This is a bit of a pain when exporting lots of images in a session, especially since I always take the default options on both dialogs.

Are there any options or tricks for avoiding these dialogs, or at least removing the first dialog (perhaps via a default export setting)?

As an example, in Adobe Lightroom there is the ability to create an Export Preset, which doesn't require any confirmation or interaction. Lightroom can also *Export With Previous* which also doesn't require further confirmation after the first time it's used. Is anything like this available in macOS Photos?

[image: Adobe Lightroom has export options which don't require interaction]

Comment: Not really an answer, but I just drag them to the desktop [or open folder] which saves the current edited version, no dialog required.

Comment: If you are always accepting the defaults then why not just press: [Shift][Command][E]-[Enter][Enter]

Comment: I could drop it in as a potential answer, in case no-one comes up with a better option.

Comment: Sorry, but when you said "and then choose > File > Export > Export 1 Photo.", I assumed you were mouse clicking through things and why I suggested just using keystrokes.  That said, anytime I have something repetitive to do I script it in one form or another. An Automator Service come to mind using either what Photo actions are available or an AppleScript action.

Comment: I've updated the _code_ in the answer and added additional info after the **Note:**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, anytime I have something repetitive to do, I *script* it in one form or another, and this is how I handle your scenario.

In **Automator**, create a new **Service** *workflow* with the following settings:

- **Service receives no input in Photos**

Add a **Run AppleScript** *action*.

- Replace the default *code* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

  ```
  set thisLocation to (path to desktop)

  tell application "Photos"
      set theseItems to selection
      if theseItems is not {} then
          -- # Remove the '--' from in front of 'with' to export the original files.
          export theseItems to thisLocation -- with using originals 
      else
          display dialog "No files were selected to export!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
              default button 1 with title "Nothing To Do" with icon 1
      end if
  end tell
  ```

Save the **Automator Service** *workflow*, e.g.: **Export Selected Files**

Assign a keyboard shortcut for it, in:

**System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **General**

- Example: **Export Selected Files       ⌃⌘E**

Now in **Photos**, after having selected the file(s) to export, press **⌃⌘E** and the selection is exported to the **Desktop**. No need to deal with multiple dialog boxes as when pressing **⇧⌘E**.

Obviously this is just *example* **AppleScript** *code* and while `thisLocation` is set to the **Desktop**, nonetheless it can be set wherever you'd like, where the folder already exists. It just has to be in the form of an *alias* if not using any of the *folder constant* [`path to (folder)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW19) locations e.g.:

`set thisLocation to alias "Macintosh HD:Temp:"`

Also, on a side note, **Automator** offers a number of different *actions* for **Photos** and those along with other *actions* provided can make for nice solutions to some repetitive tasks.

---

**Note:** As stated, this is just *example* **AppleScript** *code* and can be modified as needed beyond modifying the value of `thisLocation`, as wanted, e.g. adding `with using originals` at the end of `export theseItems to thisLocation`, or other *code* as wanted. The onus is upon the User to add any *error handling* that may be appropriate and or necessary.

When using a **Run AppleScript** *action* in **Automator**, you may find it handy to test your **AppleScript** *code* in **Script Editor**, where you'll have access to the **AppleScript Dictionary** for **Photos**, in the **Library** available from the **Window** *menu*, or press **⇧⌘L** in **Script Editor**.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for - many thanks for introducing me to the wonders of Automator. Now I'm off to automate the rest of my life...

Comment: for bonus points, do you know what the Automator syntax would be for _Export Unmodified Original_? That would be useful for exporting raw images for processing in Lightroom

Comment: @Stephen Lead, Yes it's in the "**Note:**", however it's: `export theseItems to thisLocation with using originals`. I've also updated the _code_ in the answer and added additional info after the **Note:**.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not the best answer, but in case there are no better alternatives...

I just drag them to the desktop [or open folder] which saves the current edited version, no dialog required.
Multi-selections work, as well as single items.

Comment: Here's a possible issue with _drag n drop_... In Photos, when pressing **⇧⌘E**, the default Photo Kind: is JPEG and if the selected photo is e.g. PNG, the _drag n drop_ will be PNG not JPEG.

Comment: Potentially, sure. tbh all I have in Photos is either pics from my phone, or already edited jpgs of completed Photoshop projects. I don't keep my 'important' photos in it.

Comment: What’s the down side of dragging? I believe you don’t get to choose any export options and it resamples it JPEG with some middling compression level? Perhaps also reduce the pixel size? _(in the past the drag to desktop reduced the size of raw images and format pretty dramatically since most people would then want to upload to web or email the images)_